# How to fix the width of longtable LATEX

Tags: latex, width, longtable

I want to set the width of my `longtable` so it fits within the page and not crops out. I have 206 columns and 17 rows.

I use tablesgenerator.com to get my `longtable`, but the option "Scale table to text width" doesn't work with `longtable`, could use some help. (Latex beginner here).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{}lllllllllllllllll@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{SN} & \textbf{zhelio} & \textbf{zhelio\_un} & \textbf{zCMB} & 
\textbf{zCMB\_un} & \textbf{Peak\_MJD} & \textbf{Peak\_MJD\_un} & \textbf{x1} 
& \textbf{x1\_un} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{c\_un} & \textbf{mB} & 
\textbf{mB\_un} & \textbf{t} & \textbf{t\_un} & \textbf{Host\_logmass} & 
\textbf{Host\_logmass\_un} \\* \midrule
\endhead

%table stuff here...

\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

This is what it looks like

[image]

Comment: How on earth should 206 columns fit on a paper?????????????

Comment: Even the 17 columns from the code in your question won't fit on a normal sized paper

Comment: I have a huge data file i need to include in mine assignment. But yeah 206 columns is a lot, and that is why i need help figuring out how to make it all fit. I dont mind if its 5 pages long, the width just need to be scaled down or something idk

Comment: Do you maybe mean 206 rows?

Comment: Maybe, to be honest i dont know the difference between rows and columns :) But its 205 cells long and 17 cells wide

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean 206 rows and not columns, then you could try the following strategies:

- put the table on landscape pages
- use a smaller font
- reduce the margins of your document to have more space
- reduce the space between columns

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{}lllllllllllllllll@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{SN} & \textbf{zhelio} & \textbf{zhelio\_un} & \textbf{zCMB} & 
\textbf{zCMB\_un} & \textbf{Peak\_MJD} & \textbf{Peak\_MJD\_un} & \textbf{x1} 
& \textbf{x1\_un} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{c\_un} & \textbf{mB} & 
\textbf{mB\_un} & \textbf{t} & \textbf{t\_un} & \textbf{Host\_logmass} & 
\textbf{Host\_logmass\_un} \\* \midrule
\endhead

%table stuff here...

\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]